# Nullpointer exception error on assigning variable a value

Tags: apex

I wrote a trigger to pull out campaign field values and update them on leads that meet specific criteria.

I am getting an error at line 25, column 1
The error is as followings:

> deleteThisTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.deleteThisTrigger: line 25, column 1

I'm not sure why I am getting that error since the expectation is that the lead would be getting assigned the campaign value (which from the system debug has a value)

Thanks!

```
trigger deleteThisTrigger on CampaignMember (before insert) {
    Set<Id> campaignIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (CampaignMember cm : Trigger.new) {
        if (cm.LeadId != NULL && cm.ContactId == NULL && cm.Lead.System_Type__c == NULL && cm.Lead.Systems_Group__c == NULL) {
            campaignIds.add(cm.campaignId);

          System.debug(campaignIds);
        }
    }

    Map<Id, Campaign> campaignMap = new Map<Id, Campaign> ([SELECT System_Type__c, Systems_Group__c
                                    FROM Campaign
                                    WHERE Id IN :campaignIds]);

        System.debug(campaignMap);

    for (CampaignMember cm : Trigger.new) {
        if (cm.LeadId != NULL && cm.ContactId == NULL && cm.Lead.System_Type__c == NULL && cm.Lead.Systems_Group__c == NULL) {
            Campaign thisCampaign = campaignMap.get(cm.CampaignId);

            System.debug(thisCampaign.Systems_Group__c);
            System.debug(cm.LeadId);

            **cm.Lead.Systems_Group__c = thisCampaign.Systems_Group__c;** 
            cm.Lead.System_Type__c = thisCampaign.System_Type__c;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like error is when you access `cm.Lead.Systems_Group__c`, if you want to update the leads you have to collect the lead records in a list and insert. Doesn't seem `campaignMap.get(cm.CampaignId)` would be null, better to add more system debugs.

Comment: Techincally `thisCampaign` could be null if you tried to insert a `CampaignMember` with its `CampaignId` blank.

Comment: @Adrian good point, been a while I worked on campaign and assumed campaign is a mandatory field. Confusing part was the debug lines before the actual failing line here which didn't made sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your error is because a trigger on CampaignMember has implicit access to the fields of CampaignMember ONLY via Trigger.new. Thus `cm.Lead.xxxx` will not resolve to a value as `cm.Lead` is a lookup relationship.

You'll need to collect all the CampaignMember.LeadId values and use that in a query that fetches the Lead data and save that in a map with key leadId

Comment: I pulled the leads into a list and fetched the lead data, but now hitting an issue where the lead values get overwritten regardless if they are blank or have a value.  Expected functionality would be to only overwrite if blank.

I added the new code above to my original post.

Comment: i  would suggest you mark this answer as resolved and then post a new question with the current state of the code and the current issue you are facing.